# How to rename an aggregate column in groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a group by in a pandas dataframe, how can I change the name of the aggregate column after the group by?

```
df.groupby(['open_year','open_month','source']).size().reset_index()
```

it creates a dataframe with the following columns

```
open_year, open_month, CREATED_BY_REVISED, 0
```

I', trying to rename the last colum(0) but it doesn't work

```
x.rename({'0':'xyz'})
```